# how to create class that manually perform linear regression

Tags: python, linear-regression

I am a student and starting linear regression. we've been tought a manual regression formula:
**(X.T * X) **-1 * X.T * y**
also we had an example with simple arrays:

```
from numpy.linalg import inv
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

X = np.array([[1, 50], [1, 60], [1, 70], [1, 100]]) # it MUST have this 1... a trivial variable... i don't understand for what
y = np.array([[10], [30], [40], [50]])

w = inv((X.T).dot(X)).dot(X.T).dot(y)
print(f'w_1 = {round(w[0][0], 2)},\nw_2 = {round(w[1][0], 3)}')

X_min = X[:, 1].min()
X_max = X[:, 1].max()

X_support = np.linspace(X_min, X_max, num=100)
Y_model = w[0][0] + w[1][0] * X_support

plt.scatter(x=X[:, 1], y=Y, color='g', alpha=0.8)
plt.plot(X_support, Y_model)

plt.show()
```

Now I want to do the same with multiply variables using Boston Dataset.
I need to make a class which will do "the same" as LinearRegression() does. It must have
.fit() method and .predict method. There was zero explanation how to act when array has more than 1 columns... So im confused.

Here what i did at first:

```
from numpy.linalg import inv
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston

    class CustomLinearReg:
        def __init__(self):
            pass
        
        def fit(X, y):
            return inv((X.T).dot(X)).dot(X.T).dot(y)
    
        def predict(X):
            pass
        
    boston_dataset = load_boston()
    
    X = boston_dataset.data
    y = boston_dataset.target
    
    reg = CustomLinearReg.fit(X, y)
    reg
```

but it returns only 1 coefficient and I don't sure it is right... also I don't understand where to get the second.
After that i thought that i need that "1" - trivial variable and did like that:

```
boston_dataset = load_boston()

X = boston_dataset.data.tolist()

for n1, x in enumerate(X):
    for n2, y in enumerate(x):
        X[n1][n2] = [1, y]

X = np.array(X)
y = boston_dataset.target

reg = CustomLinearReg.fit(X, y)
reg
```

but it returns

```
ValueError: shapes (2,13,506) and (506,13,2) not aligned: 506 (dim 2) != 13 (dim 1)
```

I tried some more, like calculate every coefficient one by one in a cycle... but failed.

Please help me to solve this.

I need a class that for .fit(X,y) returns pairs of coefficients and then .predict() method which makes a model after .fit().

Comment: why do you write these lines : `for n1, x in enumerate(X):  for n2, y in enumerate(x): X[n1][n2] = [1, y]`

Comment: to make array of digits like [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] look like [[1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4], [1, 5]]. adding trivial variable.

Comment: do you know in this line : `inv((X.T).dot(X)).dot(X.T).dot(y)` you are trying multiple 3d matrixes when x.shape is `506,13,2`

Comment: OK you need split your dataset in to x_train and y_train

Answer (score 0):

I think you are mixing some things up. Lets start with your formula:
`(X.T * X) **-1 * X.T * y`. This comes from the least square method. Lets take the equation of a simple line through the origin: `y(x) = a *x`.

If you want to know the value for `a` that will provide the best fit to your datapoints you can indeed use your formula for regression. `X` will be a vector of your x values for example: X = `[1,2,3,4]`. `Y` will then be the vector of your y values for example `Y=[2,4,6,8]`. The result of this equation, lets call it `P`, is the parameter vector. In this case the equation will give `P = 2`, so just a scalar and that will then be the value of `a`.

In case you have multiple parameters you want to find, for example lets take the line `y(x) = a*x + b`, the vectors will become matrices. First note that `a*x + b` is the same as `[a, b] * [x, 1]^T`. This is where the ones in your `X` matrix are coming from.

In this made up example `X = [[1,1],[2,1],[3,1],[4,1]]`, and `Y` remains the same. Using your equation will now result in `P = [2, 0]`, which means `a = 2` and `b = 0`.

Modifying your class would give something like:

```
from numpy.linalg import inv
import numpy as np


class CustomLinearReg:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a=0
        self.b=0
        
        
    def fit(self, X, y):
        R=inv(X.T@X)@X.T@y
        self.a=R[0]
        self.b=R[1]
    
    def predict(self, X):
        return X@np.array([self.a,self.b])


X = np.array([[1, 50], [1, 60], [1, 70], [1, 100]])
y = np.array([10, 30, 40, 50])

clr = CustomLinearReg()
clr.fit(X,y)

# checking on training data. 
print(clr.predict(X))

# predicting on new data
print(clr.predict(np.array([[1,20],[1,35],[1,60]])))
```

output:

```
[18.21428571 25.35714286 32.5        53.92857143]
[-3.21428571  7.5        25.35714286]
```

Comment: If would be more logical to have just your input and output data as inputs to the methods of the class, and construct the matrices including the column with ones inside the class.

Comment: here is input data to work with:
`from sklearn.datasets import load_boston`  <br>
`data = load_boston()`

Answer (score 0):

something like this:

```
class CustomLinearReg:
    def __init__(self):
       self.coef = []

    def fit(self, X, y):
    self.coef = inv((X.T).dot(X)).dot(X.T).dot(y)
        return self.coef

    def predict(self, X):
        return X.dot(self.coef)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

If train data was of 1 column - train and 2 column - test, the code would be:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score

class CustomLinearReg:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    
    def fit(X, y):
        return inv((X.T).dot(X)).dot(X.T).dot(y)

    def predict(w):
        X_min = X[:, 1].min() - X[:, 1].max() / 10
        X_max = X[:, 1].max() + X[:, 1].max() / 10
        X_support = np.linspace(X_min, X_max, num=20)
        prediction = w[0] + w[1] * X_support
        return prediction, X_support

data = pd.read_csv('..//..//Materials//3.10_non_linear.csv', sep=',')

X = np.array(data.x_train.apply(lambda x: [1, x]).tolist())
y = data.y_train

w = CustomLinearReg.fit(X, y)
y_model, X_support = CustomLinearReg.predict(w)


plt.scatter(x=X[:, 1], y=y, color='g', alpha=0.8)
plt.plot(X_support, y_model)

plt.show()
```

But it has multiply columns (features). SO....

```
data:
     x_train     y_train
0   0.138368    0.838812
1   0.157237    0.889313
2   0.188684    1.430040
3   0.685553    1.717309
4   0.874237    2.032588
5   1.182421    1.860341
6   1.251605    1.878928
7   1.270474    2.430015
8   1.402553    2.327856
9   1.427711    2.203649
10  1.471737    2.207708
11  1.534632    1.388039
12  1.553500    1.718544
13  1.842816    2.103264
14  2.018921    2.295177
15  2.289369    1.965152
16  2.641579    0.745949
17  2.685606    1.160798
18  2.798816    0.847264
19  2.823974    0.755585
20  2.912027    1.304593
21  2.924606    1.066442
22  3.270527    0.676944
23  3.314553    0.579166
24  3.528395    0.133375
25  3.597580    0.171235
26  3.761106    0.196110
27  3.773685    -0.072016
28  3.918343    0.118110
29  4.107027    0.466673
30  4.107027    0.315611
31  4.125895    0.214945
32  4.188790    0.050313
33  4.333448    0.106148
34  4.541001    0.057132
35  4.572448    -0.057252
36  4.622764    0.449234
37  4.641632    -0.336120
38  4.937238    -0.038237
39  5.125922    0.095250
40  5.157369    0.313029
41  5.258001    -0.231257
42  5.308317    0.024936
43  5.415238    0.418719
44  5.446685    0.165727
45  5.509580    0.266092
46  5.610212    0.669440
47  5.949843    0.892383
48  5.968712    1.265869
49  5.968712    0.664839
```

Comment: is this answer of your question?

Comment: no )) it is the answer of a question, IF it was an array of x_train and y_train. and i have an array: 
`from sklearn.datasets import load_boston` `data = load_boston()`